# como por valores dentro de objetos

Tags: javascript, jquery, orientação-a-objetos

Eu tenho um "*span*" com propriedades *data*:

```
 <span data-label="Name" data-icon="user"></span>
```

E no script tenho uma variável com objetos:

```
 var widgets = {
    options: {
       label: null,
       icon: null
    }
 };
```

Como posso buscar e por os valores dos *data* dentro dos objetos???

`edição`

Tentei por como está na pergunta para facilitar, mas pelo visto complicou mais. Peço desculpas kkkkk

Mas é o seguinte eu estou querendo criar "*widgets*" que execute seus papéis de acordo com o "*data-role*" fornecido, em seguida ele executa a função respectiva, com algumas opções que pode dar mais informações que no caso são outros "*data-...*", segue o código:

```
  $.widget = function(name, parameters){
        $(document).ready(function(){
              var widgets = $("[data-role=" + name + "]");
  Object.keys(parameters.options).forEach(function(key){
                    parameters.options[key] = widgets.data(key);
              });

              parameters._create(widgets);
        });
  };

  var widget = $.widget;

  $.widget("input", {

        options: {
              label: null,
              icon: null
        },

        _create: function(element){
              var o = this.options;
              $("<span/>").addClass("label fg-" + _theme_featured).text(o.label).appendTo(element);
```

Porém ele apenas coleta dados do primeiro e adiciona em todos, eu gostaria que fosse individual

Answer (score 3):

Os passos que precisas:

- ter acesso a esse elemento, por exemplo`var span = document.querySelector('span');`
- podes ter acesso aos dados desses campos `data-` com a [API nativa `.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)
- passar esses valores para o teu objeto:

---

Quando passas os valores para o objeto `widgets` podes ter duas abordagens.

a) Ou usas as chaves do objeto e vais procurar isso no DOM:

```
Object.keys(widgets.options).forEach(function(chave){
    widgets.options[chave] = span.dataset['data-' + chave];
});
```

b) Ou usas os campos `data-` do elemento e passas para o objeto. Deste modos passas todos os campos `data-` ao mesmo tempo.

... da maneira gambiarra:

```
widget.options = span.dataset;
```

... ou da maneira ES6

```
widgets.options = Object.assign({} ,span.dataset);
```

#### Exemplos: https://jsfiddle.net/rkz5fkaw/

Comment: Muito obrigado funcionou, mas ele não faz individual, como eu passo aplicar isso com vários spans individualmente cada um com seu valor? Tentei usar o _:eq()_ na seleção mas só fez com o primeiro

Comment: @Vinicius como queres os dados no `widgets`? queres um `widgets`  para cada elemento ou queres um `widgets` com os dados de todos? Podes dar um exemplo dos dados finais que queres?

Comment: Pergunta editada

Answer (score 1):

A lógica para isso seria bem simples:

```js
var widgets = {
  options: {
    label: null,
    icon: null
  }
};

var span = document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0];

widgets.options.label = span.getAttribute("data-label");
widgets.options.icon = span.getAttribute("data-icon");

document.write("<b> Span data-label: </b>" +widgets.options.label + "<br> <b> Span data-icon: </b>" + 
widgets.options.icon)
```

```html
<span data-label="Name" data-icon="user"></span>
```

Para buscar, basta colocar os nomes do objetos em um nível hierarquico e separados por um ponto ("."). Por exemplo:

```
var objeto1 = {
   objeto11: {
     objeto111: {
       chave: true
     }
   },
   objeto12: {
     objeto121: {
       chave: false
     }
   }
 }

objeto1.objeto11.objeto111.chave; // Retornaria "true"
objeto1.objeto12.objeto121.chave; // Retornaria "false"
```

Já uma das maneiras da captura do "data-.." é o `.getAttribute("data-..")`, como no meu exemplo.
Ou você poderia deteminar o valor do `data` pelo `.setAttribute("data-...", "novo valor")`. No caso, a segunda opção teria dois argumentos.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a propriedade dataset.

Ex.:

```
var span = document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0];
span.dataset.label; // "Name"
span.dataset.icon; // "User"
```

As propriedades de dataset podem ser lidas e escritas.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Ou você pode ler com o método `span.getAttribute('data-label');` e escrever com o método `span.setAttribute('data-label', 'Name');`